# Unknown Java error - semicolon underlined in red

Tags: java

I am a java beginner taking college class. I do not know why I receive this error. Could you help me?

```
public class Arithmetic {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO: Auto-generated  method stub
          }
          int number1 = 5;
          int number2 = 8;
          int number3 = 0;//error
          number3 = number1 + number2;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post text as image. We can't copy-paste it to our editors and search engine can't index this text properly. More info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766

Comment: Move the first `}` all the way down, `number3 = number1 + number2` needs to go within the `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the code into the `main` method

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    int number1 = 10;
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the first `}` all the way down. 
`number3 = number1 + number2` needs to go within the `main` method.